# Target div in parent of parent of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to target an image in the parent of the parent of the parent of my button.

Tried :

`$(event.target).parents().eq(2).$("img").css( "opacity", .3 );`

`$(event.target).parent().parent().parent().$("img").css( "opacity", .3 );`

`$(event.target).parent().parent().parent("img").css( "opacity", .3 );`

Edit: just realized it's the parent of the parent but, even modified accordingly, the code below still doesn't function.

here is the HTML:

```
<div>
<div>
<button type="button" class="page3">Read more</button></div>
</div>
<img src="img/imgs-slides/3.png" border="0" alt="">
</div>
```

js:

```
$( "button.page3" ).click(function(event) {
$(event.target).parents().eq(1).$("img").css( "opacity", .3 ); //doesnt work
$(event.target).closest("img").css( "opacity", .3 ); //neither
}
```

Comment: [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) would probably be better for this..

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the structure of the html

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button id="btn">Test</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could select the image and change the css by this

```
$(event.target).parent().parent().parent().find('img').css('opacity', '.3');
```

Or simply

```
$(event.target).parents('div').find('img').css('opacity', '.3');
```

As pointed out in the comments by @jony-Y

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pv6081cz/

Comment: why not use parents? 

$(event.target).parents("div").find('img').css('opacity', '.3');

Comment: That would work too, I was just trying to explain that the op was not using the right number of 'parent' and not the right way to find the IMG tag. I updated the answer e to include your suggestion